# Problem during GRASS working session in R environment

Tags: r, grass-gis, grass-7.2, rgrass7

I have a series of shapefile like those are in the attached folder.
I would like to realize for each column of those shapefiles a bicubic spline. I would like to use for this operation GRASS into an R work session.

Here is the script that I have achieved so far:

```
library(rgrass7)
#-Link to location and mapset
initGRASS(gisBase = "",gisDbase = "",location = "",mapset = "",override = TRUE)

tips <-list.files("path to folder",pattern='.shp',full.names=F)
#- Object list
path <-"path to folder" 
#- I use it to create g object
for (i in 1:length(tips)) {
  #print(tips[[i]])
  i <-"example_shapefile.shp"
  n<-substr(i, 1, 17) # only part "example_shapefile"
  g <-paste(path,i,sep = '/') #- Path to the file. Path is the route to file example: "C:/....." 
  ImpGr <-execGRASS(cmd = "v.in.ogr",parameters = list(input = g,output=n),flags = c("overwrite"))
  #- Import the shapefile into grass
  execGRASS('g.region',parameters=list(vector="ImpGr",res=10))
}
```

I'm writing because I can't set the characteristics of the computational region. I get an error message saying "vector map don't found but it is correctly in the mapset. Why?

[Here an example of my data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nw03YTEbkP5cM0aWRAuW2eJPOP_s7vrn?usp=sharing)

Comment: I cannot access your example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error , I believe, is in trying to use the return value of execGRASS as if it were a vector. This is not the case, the return value is just what the shell returns, usually 0 or some error value if the command fails.

WHat you need in your `g.region` command is the name of the newly created GRASS vector, the `output=` value from `v.in.ogr`.

Additionally, your for loops seems weird: you loop using the variable `i`, but then assign to that variable inside the loop.

Here is my code, perhaps better presented, for starting GRASS inside R, then importing a list of shapefiles, and setting the region to each.

```
library(rgrass7)
library(sf)
shape_dir <- "~/GIS/World"
shapefiles <- list.files(shape_dir, pattern=".shp$", full.names=TRUE)
# Get EPSG code of one shapefile, to use when creating new location
# Assuming all shapefiles are same CRS
epsg_code = st_crs(read_sf(shapefiles[1]))$epsg
epsg_code = paste0("EPSG:",epsg_code)

# Create new temporary GRASS location
# Use the EPSG code to set Location CRS
gisdbase="/tmp"
location="matt85"
mapset="PERMANENT"
location_path = file.path(gisdbase,location)
# The -e flag tells grass to create location and exit
system2("grass78",  args=paste('-c', epsg_code, '-e', location_path))

# Use system2 command to get path to grass installation
grass_path <- system2("grass78", args="--config path", stdout=TRUE)

# Now we are ready for initGRASS
initGRASS(gisBase=grass_path,
        gisDbase=gisdbase,
        location=location,
        mapset=mapset,
        remove_GISRC=TRUE, override=TRUE)
# Start looping thru shapefiles
lapply(shapefiles, function(shp) {
  vect_name = gsub(pattern=".shp", replacement="", x=basename(shp))
  execGRASS(cmd="v.import",
            parameters=list(input=shp, output=vect_name),
            flags="overwrite")
  execGRASS(cmd="g.region",
            parameters=list(vector=vect_name),
            flags=c("a","p"))
  # Do whatever on shapefile
  }
```

HTH

Comment: Hello! thank you for your answer. The code works.