# Working iteratively on GRASS in R environment

Tags: r, grass-gis, grass-7.0, grass-7.2, rgrass7

I would like to realize a bicubic spline for many shapefiles. Following the indications on this post,[enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413498/problem-during-grass-working-session-in-r-environment/413547#413547) I obtained my results and export it from GRASS to folder.

Now, I would like to obtain the same result for many columns (from 4 to 10) in the shapefile. I think to realize a for loop to be inserted into the function.

How can I set up a similar for loop cycle?

I also attach a small sample of my [data here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nw03YTEbkP5cM0aWRAuW2eJPOP_s7vrn?usp=sharing).

Comment: Based on your previous question, I guess you want to work in an R session. Can you clarify you reason for running GRASS commands from R? Why not do this looping  and spline interpolation directly in GRASS?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer you referred to in your question, here's a continuation that allows you to loop thru all the columns in a GRASS vector. You get the list of columns from the `v.info -c` GRASS command . The trick is to parse the result in R.

```
library(rgrass7)
library(sf)

shape_dir <- "./example_files"
shapefiles <- list.files(shape_dir, pattern=".shp$", full.names=TRUE)
# Use first *.prj file for georeferencing
prj_file <- list.files(shape_dir, pattern=".prj$", full.names=TRUE)[1]

# Create new temporary GRASS location
gisdbase="/tmp"
location="matt85"
mapset="PERMANENT"
location_path = file.path(gisdbase,location)
# Use system2 to create GRASS location (and exit)
system2("grass78",  args=paste('-c', prj_file, '-e', location_path))

# Use system2 command again to get path to grass installation
grass_path <- system2("grass78", args="--config path", stdout=TRUE)

# Now we are ready for initGRASS
initGRASS(gisBase=grass_path,
        gisDbase=gisdbase,
        location=location,
        mapset=mapset,
        remove_GISRC=TRUE, override=TRUE)

# Start looping thru shapefiles
lapply(shapefiles, function(shp) {
  vect_name = gsub(pattern=".shp", replacement="", x=basename(shp))
  execGRASS(cmd="v.import",
            parameters=list(input=shp, output=vect_name),
            flags="overwrite")
  execGRASS(cmd="g.region",
            parameters=list(vector=vect_name, res="10"),
            flags=c("a","p"))
  # Get columns from v.info with the `-c` flag
  columns <- execGRASS('v.info', parameters=list(map=vect_name), flags=c("c", "quiet"))  
  columns <- attr(columns, which="resOut")
  # and loop thru the columns, extract name of each column
  lapply(columns, function(col) {
    # split out the data type from the column name
    col_name = unlist(strsplit(col, split='|', fixed=TRUE))[2]
    # Now do whatever you want with this column
    print(paste("Working on column:", col_name))
  })
})
```